# certification scores published?

Tags: force.com, certification

I have my Certified Force.com Developer  exam soon, and I wanted to know if a company can see your actual score or just pass/fail. Also, do companies ever really care/ask about your score?

Sorry, **i know this isn't the typical type of question to ask here,** but i knew that  someone around here would be able to give a quick answer

thanks in advance!

Comment: You never get to see the score,you get only a pass/fail on the exam, added certifications are handy to get a job, and what happens after is the history.

Comment: Good luck for your exam, dont worry too much, read the questions carefully and you should be alright :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The other answers still stand. Additionally, Salesforce launched a [verification service](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/credentials/verification). If you have selected to make your certs visible (highly recommended) they are searchable by name and email.

You can link the page ([for example](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/certification-detail-print?searchString=SyxydwfMuNP/8eeja3MvAIL39fkA7R0SIt37iKJ26xt6sVNhTZFEzQdOlupnKFHV)) to add supporting evidence to your documentation as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

At this time there is no registry of certificates, where an individual's certificates can be verified. Typically, people furnish screenshots of their Webassessor homepage with the list of certificates, or mail the certificates that they receive in the email on passing.

Scores are never displayed, only Pass/ Fail.

Answer (score 14):

You never find out your score, ever. The only thing Salesforce will ever disclose to you or anyone else about an exam is Pass or Fail.

You will get feedback on Pass/Fail on most of the exams (all except for Advanced Developer/Technical Architect) the instant you submit it. So, no worries about getting the A+. Just worry about passing!

Good luck on your exam tomorrow!